# Alternative for :id param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I have `resources :users` and `custom_id` inside users table.

I want to use `link_to "user", user` method choosing `custom_id` to provide link with this field as param.

My `show` action inside **users_controller.rb**:

```
...
  @user = User.find(custom_id: params[:id])
...
```

Comment: I think you need something like: `link_to "user", user_path(@user, :custom_id => some_id)`

Comment: Post the code for User's model and migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your form You could use:

```
<%= link_to @user.name, @user %>
```

because You already wrote in UsersController:

```
...
  @user = User.find(custom_id: params[:id])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to manage this is via the `to_param` method which you can define inside a model.  When you pass a model instance into a path helper, it calls this method on it, which by default returns the id.  You could override it to use `custom_id` instead.

```
#in User class
def to_param
  self.custom_id
end
```

Now you can say

```
link_to "user", user_path(@user)
```

and it will generate html like

```
<a href="/users/<@user.custom_id>">user</a>
```

and so @user.custom_id will come through in `params[:id]`.

You will still need to make sure that you load the user via the custom id field, rather than the id, in the controller.  A common pattern is to put it into a protected method in the controller:

```
#in UsersController
protected

def load_user
  @user = User.find(custom_id: params[:id])
end
```

now you can say `load_user` in all the actions which load @user, or put it into a before filter for the relevant actions, which is even DRYer.